# How to drop columns which contains specific characters except one column?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas dataframe is having 5 columns which contains 'verifier' in it. I want to drop all those columns which contained 'verified in it except the column named 'verified_90'(Pandas dataframe). I am trying following code but it is removing all columns which contains that specific word.

Column names: verified_30   verified_60 verified_90 verified_365 logo.verified. verified.at etc

''''

```
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='Test')))]
```

''''

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use a regex approach here:

```py
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='^(?!verified_90$).*verified.*$')))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter columns with not verified OR with `verified_90` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), here `:` means select all rows and columns by mask:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('verified') | (df.columns == 'verified_90')]
```